# Stable homotopy as generalized homology

Tags: reference-request, homotopy-theory

I want to find some references that stable homotopy groups satisfied to Eilenberg-Steenrod axioms (without axiom of dimension, of course). I only find in [this paper](http://homepages.math.uic.edu/~mholmb2/stable.pdf) that homotopy theory forms *reduced* generalized homology theory. Hope for your help.

Comment: A good place to start (you'll have to do some work) is Strom's book "Modern Classical Homotopy Theory", section 22.2.1, pg 505.

Comment: Thank you, but I already found in http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/gww9.pdf (p.248) that generalized reduced homology contain the same information as generalized homology. So, with paper in my start post it is close question in some sense.